# How can I tell if a screenshot was made in IE7 or IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, web-development

I have a screenshot of an IE web browser. My question is, how can I tell whether it's IE 7 or IE8?

I've looked on the net and all the different shots of 7 and 8 look the same.

Comment: This is also useful for answering the same question about which version of IE a person is using as you look over their shoulder.

Comment: I think you mean "How can I tell the difference between IE7 and IE8 in a screenshot?", since (AFAIK), by default, Internet Explorer doesn't have the ability to take screenshots of itself.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at the website address shown in the address box.

In Internet Explorer 7, the entire address is black:

[image: IE7]

In Internet Explorer 8, only the main domain name is black, the rest of the address is gray:

[image: IE8]

Answer (score 11):

It is very hard to tell from just a screen shot. Initially I thought I spotted two differences, but as it seems I was wrong and there is only one.

IE7 screenshot:
[image]

IE8 screenshot:
[image]

On a default installation, IE8 and IE7 display the favorites button differently. I am not sure if this is customizable, but without any customization it should look different.

You should use this only as a hint and not as a definitive way of telling the browser version. The look of a browser can be heavily modified using different plugins / themes.

(This was [originally posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4346353/screen-print-of-ie7-and-ie8/4346469#4346469) for the question on Stack Overflow, but the answer didn't get migrated along with the question.)

Answer (score 5):

IE8 should have the compatability tag after the address bar.
I don't think Ie7 has that.
See Image below:

[image]

However looking at certain sites i.e BBC.co.uk some don;t seem to have the compatibility buton showing on the bar. You could see if it has it and check the website displayed though. Should give you an idea.

Comment: A user can hide that button easily enough anyway, so the absence of it wouldn't be conclusive.

Answer (score 4):

1. Have a look at the color of the tab. IE 8 introduced colored tabs.
2. Also post the image so that we can have a shot at guessing the browser.

[image: IE 8 Colored Tab]

Comment: What about the back and forward buttons would give you a clue about the version?

Comment: In addition to being coloured, the tabs in IE8 were also slightly ... 'flatter' than in IE7.